# Haskell: List of words paired with a number in a tuple

Tags: list, function, haskell, tuples

I need help getting from stage 4 to stage 5. I'm not sure of a Haskell function that takes each element and puts it in a tuple. Perhaps I have do this manually, which I'm also not sure how to do.

Here is my functions so far:

```
splitLines :: String -> [[String]]
splitLines splitLinesStr = splitWords (lines splitLinesStr)

splitWords :: [String] -> [[String]]
splitWords splitWordList = map words splitWordList

tupleNums tupleNumList = zip [1..] tupleNumList
```

Stage 1: the original input, for example,

```
"a&b b c.\na dd\n"
```

Stage 2: the original input, split into a list of lines, as in

```
["a&b b c.", "a dd"]
```

Stage 3: the list of lines, split further into a list of list of words, as in

```
[["a", "b", "b", "c"], ["a", "dd"]]
```

Stage 4: the list of lists, "tupled" so that line numbers are attached to them, as in

```
[(1,["a", "b", "b", "c"]), (2,["a", "dd"])]
```

Stage 5: the list of words (all at the top level) where each is paired with its line number, as in

```
[(1,"a"), (1,"b"), (1,"b"), (1,"c"), (2,"a"), (2,"dd")]
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add another stage: a single tuple `(a, [b,c,d])` to the list `[(a,b), (a,c), (a,d)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is apply a combination of `map` and `concat`. Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> let x = [(1,["a", "b", "b", "c"]), (2,["a", "dd"])]
λ> map (\(y,z) -> map (\a -> (y,a)) z) x
[[(1,"a"),(1,"b\"),(1,"b"),(1,"c")],[(2,"a"),(2,"dd")]]
```

Note that I use two `map` functions. The outer `map` will traverse the elements of `x`. Each element of `x` (which is a tuple) is pattern matched by `(y,z)`. We know that `z` is a list. So, we use another `map` to traverse the list `z`. This inner `map` function will return a tuple of `(y,a)` where `a` is the current element which is being traversed in the list `z` and `y` is the first element of the tuple.

Now all you need to do is apply `concat` function on the resulting list:

```
λ> concat $ map (\(y,z) -> map (\a -> (y,a)) z) x
[(1,"a"),(1,"b"),(1,"b"),(1,"c"),(2,"a"),(2,"dd")]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can design a function to take each element of that stage-4 list as so:

```
helper :: (Int, [a]) -> [(Int, a)]
helper (num, xs) = zip (repeat num) xs
```

and then we can just use `concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`:

```
fourToFive :: [(Int, [a])] -> [(Int, a)]
fourToFive = concatMap helper
```

And that is all. Here's an example:

```
λ> fourToFive [(1, ["This", "is", "a", "line."]), (2,["This","is","another."])]
[(1,"This"),(1,"is"),(1,"a"),(1,"line."),(2,"This"),(2,"is"),(2,"another.")]
```

Comment: Just a side note, `helper = uncurry (zip . repeat)`.